# Electron angularjs ui-router not loading ui-view on mac

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, electron

I have an app in Electron that works perfectly on windows, but when trying to run on mac, it wont load the first ui-view. Maybe this is a path issue cross os?

No errors on state change, console, or loading any files, but the ui-view is empty.

Folders:

```
app
  - js
    app.js (angular main)
  - views
    index.html
    root.html
    login.html
  main.js (electron main)
```

Template:

```
<div ui-view="root"></div>
```

State:

```
$stateProvider
.state('app', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/',
    views: {
        root: {
            templateUrl: '../views/root.html',
        },
    }
})
.state('app.login', {
    url: '',
    views: {
        content: {
            templateUrl: '../views/login.html'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for adding those tags Vadim. I had just come back to edit cause I realized I had forget the angular ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by going from ui-router 0.2.15 to 0.2.18. Not exactly sure which bug was causing the issue.